# Docker push use of closed network connection

Tags: windows, docker, connection, push, dockerhub

When trying to push a big file to Docker Hub (4GB),

```
docker push name/image:latest
```

it stops half way after a few hours with the error "use of closed network connection" and the file is not pushed.

```
write tcp 192.xxx>192.xxx: use of closed network connection
```

This might be due to an unstable connection. It has 2Mb/s in upload.

How can I ask Docker or Windows to keep pushing even if there is a short disconnection?

Note: the small files are pushed correctly.

Comment: I have basically always had this problem with very large layers, even with relatively good network connectivity; my past experience is that the largest practical size for a single layer is around 1 GiB.  Repeating the `docker push` will make it try again, and it's at least clever enough to not push the layers that have already been uploaded.  Can you restructure the Dockerfile to have more smaller layers?

Comment: I have already divided by many layers thanks to separated COPY instructions, but some files have several GB and cannot be divided. Is it possible to divide one file in several layers?

Comment: Not a single answer from Docker support. Maybe pushing from github could solve this issue.

Comment: I've solved this issue with a better connection in upload. With 10Mb/s in upload, it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After many trials and investigations, I've found that there is a kind of time-out with slow connections.

I've changed to a better connection of 10Mb/s and Docker has pushed the large files correctly.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this by using a different internet connection.

The issue is likely not related to the speed of the connection. The failing connection reached 38Mb/s (up) on speed test and is never flaky in any way.

Then I switched to smartphone as a hotspot which tested an average of 8Mb/s upload. The hotspot connection succeeded in pushing the image to repository.

Comment: Did you also transfer a file having more than 4GB?

Comment: Same for me. Was pushing up a 400mb layer and it just wouldn't complete on my xfinity cable connection, but it finished successfully (albeit much more slowly) on my 5g hotspot with 1 bar.